# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte in Visual Studio Code

Tags: unicode, visual-studio-code, python-3.7

I am using Visual Studio Code 2017 edition and facing an error while reading a file in Python 3.7 version.

**The Code is:**

import sys

import codecs

import os

myfile = open('D://pythonread1.docx' , encoding = "utf8")

f = myfile.read()

print(f)

**The Error is:**

File "D:\Python3.7\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode

```
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte

I spent almost 4+ hours to search all options, but adding a utf8 or utf-8 does not resolve the problem. Also tried changing the settings for AutoguessEncoding as True or False, but did not work. The default encoding setting is utf8 in settings section.

It would be really helpful, if can get solution on this.

Thanks

Comment: Then the file does not contain UTF-8; but without seeing it, we can't tell you what it might then contain. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Are you attempting to read a .docx file as text? That is not going to work! Assuming it is a proper word document then the file is actually compressed using zip and contains other files

Comment: It's a single file with one word inside as " Helloooooo".

Comment: Is one of the o in Hellooo the character Ò? That's the character for the "invalid" 0xD2 in a Windows 1252 Encoding for example. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252
In any case as already mentioned. The file is not encoded with UTF8.
Open the file with a Unicode aware Text Editor (try with Visual Studio Code) and be sure to save it in the UTF8 format.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all the suggestion. The mistake I made was the same as "Phuzi" mentioned. I changed the file to .txt and utf8 was able to read it and print it.